# Unable to call static C# method from C++/Cli

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm trying to call a C# method from C++/Cli. This method is defined in `ClassLibrary1.dll`. I keep getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Int32
>   ClassLibrary1.Class1.getNum()'.

Here is my C++/Cli code:

```
//CppClr.cpp

#include "CppClr.h"
#using "ClassLibrary1.dll"
using namespace ClassLibrary1;
int main()
{
    System::Console::WriteLine("Start");
    int num = Class1::getNum();
    System::Console::WriteLine(num);
    System::Console::ReadLine();
}
```

My C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int getNum()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to access an old version of the C# DLL?

Comment: If it compiles but fails at runtime I'd say you are running with the wrong DLL version.

Comment: You guys are both right, it was an older version!!! (Embarrassing). Thank you, it's working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MissingMethodException is always caused by loading the wrong assembly at runtime.  Typically an old one.

An easy mistake to make in a solution that has both a C# and a C++/CLI project.  They have different standards, the C# assembly gets built to the project's bin\Debug directory but the C++/CLI project gets built to the solution's Debug directory.  You probably already discovered this, fixed it by copying the C# assembly yourself and forgot to do it again after changing the C# code.

Just make sure that both projects build to the *same* directory.  Right-click the C# project > Properties > Build tab > Output path setting.  Change it from "bin\Debug" to "..\Debug".  Repeat for the Release configuration.  Rebuild and verify you see an up to date copy of the EXE and the DLL in solution's Debug directory.